# Codeigniter: file upload working on localhost but not on server (Unexpected end of JSON input)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

Trying to upload an image to the /assets/images/ directory and it works on localhost but when pushed to the server the same code doesn't work and the console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I've updated the .htaccess file to show the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|upload|robots\.txt|.*\.css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but that didn't help

On submit:

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e){
      var newoi = $( "tr:last" ).data('order_index') + 1;
      $('input[name="order_index"]').attr('value',newoi);
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url('billboard/do_upload');?>',
        type:"post",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
          console.log(data);
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          $('#gallery').append('<tr class="photos" id="' + data.id +'" data-order_index="' + data.order_index + '"><td><button class="up"> ^ </button><button class="down"> v </button></td><td><img src="/assets/images/' + data.url + '"></td><td><button class="delete">delete</button></td></tr>');
          bindDeactivate();
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
          alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
      });
    });
```

and the console on localhost outputs:

```
{"success":true,"id":32,"location_id":"2","url":"eb3bc54c5c8d1261d3ef0cf75a32b17f.png","order_index":"1"}
```

but on my server it outputs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (index:155)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (<anonymous>:1:781)
    at Object.send (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (index:144)
```

The php code it hits:

```
  function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']="./assets/images";
    $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload("file")){
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

      $location_id= $this->input->post('location_id');
      $url = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
      $order_index = $this->input->post('order_index');


      $data = array(
        'location_id' => $location_id,
        'url' => $url,
        'order_index' => $order_index
      );


      $result['success'] = $this->db->insert('billboard_photos', $data);
      $result['id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
      $result['location_id'] = $location_id;
      $result['url'] = $url;
      $result['order_index'] = $order_index;

      echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

I'm not for sure what is causing the issue, but I've read it could be something to do with the htaccess file.  I've removed the index.php from the url, but it is served on https:// so I don't know if that is part of the issue.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: For debugging purpose hit the ajax url in browser to see the output

Comment: nothing pops up, it posts to that url

Comment: print upload  image in php ,maybe it is file permission issue - if($this->upload->do_upload("file"))
{ //upload code  }
else
{
  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  var_dump($error); exit;
}

Comment: Post the full url here

Comment: It's a secured page, so you would have to be logged in to access, so unfortunately the full url wouldn't help much

Comment: Probably you are getting an HTTP 500 on server side. Look at apache/nginx error log to see what's going on.